# AES-256 implementation in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cryptography, aes

256
but it doesnt seems to be working in GAE.I have download the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" and local_policy.jar,US_export_policy.jar are present in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\security location.

here is the code:

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncrypter {

private static final byte[] SALT = {
    (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
    (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
};
private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
private Cipher ecipher;
private Cipher dcipher;

AESEncrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] iv = ecipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
}

public String encrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = encrypt.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(bytes);
    return new Base64().encodeBase64String(encrypted);
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain) throws Exception {
    return ecipher.doFinal(plain);
}

public String decrypt(String encrypt) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(encrypt);
    byte[] decrypted = decrypt(bytes);
    return new String(decrypted, "UTF8");
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt) throws Exception {
    return dcipher.doFinal(encrypt);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String message = "MESSAGE";
    String password = "PASSWORD";

    AESEncrypter encrypter = new AESEncrypter(password);
    String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(message);
    String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

    System.out.println("Encrypt(\"" + message + "\", \"" + password + "\") = \"" + encrypted + "\"");
    System.out.println("Decrypt(\"" + encrypted + "\", \"" + password + "\") = \"" + decrypted + "\"");
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!!

Comment: but if you put  private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 128; it is working fine..

Comment: What error are you seeing? Please post a stacktrace.

Comment: here it is ::Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at com.motorola.gst.AESEncrypter.<init>(AESEncrypter.java:33)
 at com.motorola.gst.AESEncrypter.main(AESEncrypter.java:65)

Comment: Thanks for the exception. It is always a better idea to edit your original question and add this sort of information there. It's very difficult to read as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is definitely caused by missing unlimited strength jurisdiction files.

You've stated that these have been downloaded and stored in your Java 6 JDK. I would ensure you have also stored copies in the `lib/security` folder of your JRE installation too, if you have one.

Make sure you know exactly which `java` command is being invoked when your application is executed.

Comment: Thanks jones!! Copied those jarsin JRE's lib/security.It works